# Which Join for SQL plus query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 4 tables, I would like to select one column from each table, but only if the department has both 'Mick' and 'Dave working in it (must have both names, not one or the other). But it does not seem to be working properly:

```
SELECT SCHOOL_NAME, TOWN, COUNTY
FROM STUDENTS 
NATURAL JOIN SCHOOLS NATURAL JOIN TOWNS NATURAL JOIN 
COUNTIES
WHERE FIRST_NAME IN ('Mick','Dave)
/
```

I'm going wrong somewhere (probably lots of places :( ). Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `NATURAL JOIN`.  It is an abomination, because it does not take properly declared foreign key relationships into account.  It only looks at the names of columns.  This can introduce really hard to find errors.

Second, what you want is aggregation:

```
select sc.SCHOOL_NAME, t.TOWN, c.COUNTY
from STUDENTS st join
     SCHOOLS sc
     on st.? = sc.? join
     TOWNS t 
     on t.? = ? join
     COUNTIES c
     on c.? = t.?
where FIRST_NAME in ('Mick', 'Dave')
group by sc.SCHOOL_NAME, t.TOWN, c.COUNTY
having count(distinct st.first_name) = 2;
```

The `?` are placeholders for table and column names.  If you are learning SQL, it is all the more important that you understand how columns line up for joins in different tables.

A `where` clause can only check the values in a single row.  There is a separate row for each student, so there is no way -- with just a `where` -- to find both students.  That is where the aggregation comes in.

Comment: Hi,. thanks for the reply, when i use ? i receive an 'invalid character'

Comment: @user9783971 . . . As I explain in the answer `?` are placeholders for the proper column/table references.  Your question doesn't show sample data or the structure of the tables, so it is not clear what those are.  *You* need to fill them in with the right values.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least `three Join conditions`, and properly end the string `Dave` with quote :

```
SELECT SCHOOL_NAME, TOWN, COUNTY
  FROM SCHOOLS h 
  JOIN TOWNS t ON (t.id=h.town_id) 
  JOIN COUNTIES c ON (t.county_id=c.id) 
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT school_id 
                  FROM STUDENTS s
                 WHERE s.first_name in ('Mick','Dave')
                   AND school_id = h.id
                GROUP BY school_id
                HAVING count(1)>1
                  );
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/adbb3/11)

Comment: Hi, This list all students under the name mick and dave, i need it to only list the school with both mick and dave

Comment: @user9783971 OK, i changed the SQL and th Demo, as far as I understand from your comment. Please edit your Question according to this comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytic function in a sub-query to count the students who have the name `Mick` or `Dave` for each `school_id` (assuming that is your identifier for a school):

```
SELECT SCHOOL_NAME, TOWN, COUNTY
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM   (
         SELECT d.*,
                COUNT(
                  DISTINCT
                  CASE WHEN FIRST_NAME IN ( 'Mick', 'Dave' ) THEN FIRST_NAME END
                ) OVER( PARTITION BY school_id )
                  AS num_matched
         FROM   STUDENTS d
       )
       WHERE num_matched = 2
     )
     NATURAL JOIN SCHOOLS
     NATURAL JOIN TOWNS
     NATURAL JOIN COUNTIES;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/adbb3/13)

You would also be better to use an `INNER JOIN` and explicitly specify the join condition rather than relying on `NATURAL JOIN`.